# Why does an inherited border-color attribute become ineffective?

Tags: html, css, colors, border

I have a div element within a div element. The outer div has style attributes for `color` and `border-color`. The inner div inherits it.

```
<html>
  <head><style>#foo{color: red; border-color: green;}</style></head>
  <body>
    <div id="foo" style="border-width: 6; border-style: solid; padding: 10;">
      <div style="border-width: 6; border-style: solid; height: 10;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I render this on the browser, the outer div has its border rendered in green, as expected, but the inner div has its border rendered in red, unexpectedly to me.

[image: embedded divs]

When I look at Google Chrome's developer's tool, both `color` and `border-color` attributes are effective for the outer div:

[image: outer div]

but for the inner div, which inherits the attributes, `color` is effective but `border-color` is ineffective, and as a result, the border color becomes red, which is the color specified by the `color` attribute:

[image: inner div]

Why is the inherited `border-color` attribute ineffective? Is there a way to make it effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `border-color`, unlike some css properties, doesn't have `inherit` as its default value.

So you have to specify it to be `border-color: inherit`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3f8vgd35/

[W3 Description](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-color) states that it is **Inherited: NO**

Comment: If `border-color` is not inherited, which I believe is right, do you have any idea why it appeared as inherited (with shading) in Google Chrome's developer's tool? That is misleading to me.

Comment: Actually, Chrome's tool is showing the whole css rule inherited, but the fact that `border-color` has a lower opacity shows that  the specific property is not being rendered. On the top of that view, change the tab from `Styles` to `Computed` to see what's actually being rendered to the element. Mark the select box to show the inherited properties, and see that there's no `border-color`

Answer (score 3):

By definition, [`border-color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border-color) is not inherited (unless you explicitly assign the value `inherit` to it). The inner `div` does not have `border-color` on it, so it takes the initial value, which is by definition the value of the `color` property of the element.

So you need to set `border-color` explicitly on the element.